# How to restrict content using AWS lambda edge

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I'm fairly new to the whole AWS environment, about 1 month into learning and it is definitely a lot to take in but at the same time it is amazing.

I'm working from some project examples.  This one I'm on uses a NextJS boilerplate and has its content split into different steps.  Each step will have somewhat different content and their URLs would look something like:

Step 1: https://step-1.testing.xxxx.com/
Step 2: https://step-2.testing.xxxx.com/
Step 3: https://step-3.testing.xxxx.com/

Same for staging.

I'm trying to figure out how to make sure content stored in a particular folder (https://xxxx.com/protected-content/) password is not accessible in source and is accessible only after basic password auth. I want to make sure that it’s not readily visible in source code and also that it doesn’t get included in any other step EXCEPT for step 3.

Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Still trying to wrap my head around it as I would like to apply this to some personal projects I have plans to do in the future. Thank you!!!